# Why is it convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I've got following function:
$(1-\theta)\int_{y<q}|y-q|dF(y)+\theta\int_{y\geq q}|y-q|dF(y)$, where $\theta \in (0,1)$ which I need to minimize over $q$. So, I can calculate the first derivative to find which point could be a minimum. But how can I be sure that this point is indeed minimum, and not maximum? The justification of this provided in the source text is that we handle the convex minimization problem. And here is my question: what is reasoning behind this? Of course, I can do some calculations and proof the inequality from definition of convex function, but I bet that there is some neat way to proof that much faster. Of course, the absolute value under the integral is convex function of q. From what I know the sum of two convex function is also convex and I believe that due to the fact that $\theta \in (0,1)$, this linear combination is also convex. But why both integrals are convex?

Full answer to @copper.hat comment:
$\theta$ is fixed, I need to minimize just over $q$. I forgot to mention that F is a distribution function of continuous random variable, so I believe the problem is differantiable.

So to calculate the derivative I write it as follows: 
$\left(\theta-1\right)\int_{y<q}\left(y-q\right)dF\left(y\right)+\theta\int_{y\geq q}(y-q)dF\left(y\right)
$ and then the first derivative is:
$\left(1-\theta \right)\int_{y<q}dF\left(y\right)-\theta\int_{y\geq q}dF\left(y\right)= \left(1-\theta \right)F\left(q\right)-\theta\left[1-F\left(q\right)\right]= F\left(q\right)-\theta F\left(q\right)-\theta+\theta F\left(q\right)= F\left(q\right)-\theta$,
so the minimum can be in a point $q=F^{-1}(\theta)$

Thanks to @Syuizen, I have a justification based on calculation of second derivative. But to be honest I still hope for some reason that would provide justificatio and avoid calculating the second derivative.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, or what are the parameters of optimisation ($q, \theta$ or just $q$). How would you calculate the first derivative, the functional is not necessarily differentiable everywhere. For (differentiable) convex problems, first order conditions are typically necessary & sufficient.

Comment: $\theta$ is fixed, I need to minimize just over $q$. I forgot to mention that F is a distribution function of continuous random variable, so I believe the problem is differantiable.

So to calculate the derivative I write it as follows: 
$\mathbb{E}\rho_{\theta}(Y-q)=\left(\theta-1\right)\int_{y<q}\left(y-q\right)dF\left(y\right)+\theta\int_{y\geq q}(y-q)dF\left(y\right)
$ and then,

Comment: I'm asking about the reason why the point $q=F^{-1}(\theta)$ is indeed the minimum. If it is a convex optimization problem (as stated in a source text) this point is minimum. But why it is a CONVEX optimization problem? I can't see this without using the definition of convexity and I believe it has much more straightforward explanation.

Comment: The problem is convex hence first order conditions are necessary & sufficient. Since the derivative is $F(q)-\theta$, any $q$ satisfying $F(q)=\theta$ is a solution. Without extra conditions the minimiser need not be unique as far as I can see.

Comment: But why exactly is it a convex problem?

Comment: If $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ is convex for each $t$ then the functional $x \mapsto \int f(x,t) d \mu(t)$ is convex.

Comment: Well, that is something I've already knew. What I am puzzled about is how to proof the convexity (in other way than calculating from definition).

Comment: I'm confused. You know the fact I stated, so what exactly are you asking then?

Comment: I just don't see why this very function is a convex function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment
\begin{eqnarray}
(1-\theta)\int_{y<q}|y-q|dF(y)+\theta\int_{y\geq q}|y-q|dF(y) &=& (1-\theta)\int (q-y)_+ dF(y)+\theta\int (y-q)_+ dF(y)
\end{eqnarray}
where $x_+ = \max(x,0)$.

The function $q \mapsto (1-\theta)(q-y)_+ +\theta(y-q)_+$ is convex
for each $y$, hence the integral over $y$ is as well.

Comment: Is there any theorem saying that the integral from non-negative convex function is convex as well? what about the integral of x^2 which is not convex?

Comment: @jakes: You are confusing me again. See my second comment to the question (you mentioned that that was something you already knew). In general, the convex sum of convex functions is convex, the integral is just a generalisation of this (plus some technical conditions). I have no idea what you mean about the integral of $x^2$ being not convex. What is $x$, what are you integrating with respect to, what domain???

Comment: You gave me the definition of convex functional, which I was familiar with.

Could you share this technical conditions needed to convexity of integral?

I just thought about function $x \rightarrow x^2$. The integral $\int x^2 dx=\frac{1}{3}x^3$ is not convex at all if a domain contain the 0 which is the inflection point.

Comment: I think you are just trolling me.

Comment: No, I don't. Sorry if you had got such an impression. Maybe it's due to my English, or I just don't see some obvious part, but I still would like to understand why you state that 'the convex sum of convex functions is convex, the integral is just a generalisation of this (plus some technical conditions)'. I do not know any theorem saying that and I can't see the reason based on what has been wrote.

Comment: Convex just means that $f(tx+(1-t)y) \le t f(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. If you have a function $(x,t) \mapsto f(x,t)$, and the restriction $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ is convex for each $t$, then if, for example, the function $t  \mapsto f(x,t)$ is integrable for each $x$ then the function $\psi(x) = \int f(x,t) d \mu(t)$ is convex.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are getting at with the $x^2$. You are integrating over a different variable in the question. The integration is over $y$ not $q$.

Comment: The integrals I am using are definite. By $\int f(x,t) d \mu(t)$ I mean to integrate over the whole space.

Comment: I just used the $x^2$ function as a counterexample to the statement that the  integral of convex function is convex. It isn't directly related with function from the initial question.

Comment: @jakes: Look, I only have so much time for this. I am not stating that the indefinite integral of a convex function is a convex function. I am saying that if you have a function of two variables $x,t$ and for each fixed $t$ the function is convex in $x$ , then the integral of the function with respect to $t$ is a convex function of $x$. The function $(x,t) \mapsto x^2$ is still a convex function when you integrate with respect to $t$.

Comment: The question is about a function of the form $(q,y) \mapsto g(q,y)$ and you are asking about the convexity of the function $q \mapsto \int g(q,y) dF(y)$. I don't know where the indefinite integral of $x^2$ thing is coming from.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for every of your comment. Although It took me quite a lot of time to see it, it's indeed solution to my problem.

Comment: Excuse my impatience. Your comment that you already knew the result confused me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The second derivative of your function is exactly the density function $F'(x)$, which is non-negative. Hence your function is convex.

Comment: Right, density is non-negative. But it gives me convexity, don't I need the strictly convex function to have an unique minimizer?

What would be the explanation if I change the absolute value with square and have the following?
$(1-\theta)\int_{y<q}(y-q)^2dF(y)+\theta\int_{y\geq q}(y-q)^2dF(y)$, where $\theta \in (0,1)$

Comment: @jakes You are right. Then you need density function to be locally positive around a minimizer to ensure its uniqueness.

Comment: Could you drop me a hint how I can proof the locally positiveness?

Comment: @jakes It depends on the distribution of Random Variable. If there is no further information about RV, I guess we cannot do anything about uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you! how would you handle the problem with square under the integral? The referring to density function won't apply here..

Comment: @jakes If you ask for checking convexity, I will always compute the second derivative when possible. For your square problem, the second derivative is $g(q)=2(1-2\theta )F(q)+2\theta$. Since F(q) and \theta are both between 0 and 1, g(q) is non-negative.

Comment: I can see that $g(q)>2F(q)-2\theta$, but if $F(q)$ is close to $0$ and $\theta$ is close to $1$ it still can be negative, right?

Comment: @jakes If $\theta \le 0.5$, g(q) is positive. If $\theta > 0.5$, $\min g(q)=2\theta+2(1-2\theta)=2(1-\theta)>0$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But to be honest I still hope for some justification which will avoid the computation of second derivative.

Comment: @jakes Good luck. Please drop me a note if you find something more tricky :)

Comment: sure! I'll keep that in mind

Comment: I gave it an another thought and started wondering if non-negative second derivative gives me the convex problem every time. If second derivative is zero, can't we have an inflection point?